# Is there are relationship between the eigenvectors and the real Schur vectors of a real skew-symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, skew-symmetric-matrices, schur-decomposition

A real skew-symmetric matrix $A$ can be diagonalized with complex eigenvectors and pure imaginary eigenvalues:

$$A=V S V^*$$

where $S$ is:

$$S = \begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda_1\mathrm{i} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_1\mathrm{i} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -\lambda_2\mathrm{i} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_2\mathrm{i} & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
all $\lambda_i$ are real and positive, and $V$ is a complex unitary matrix.

Similarly, $A$ can be real-Schur-decomposed, with both real Schur form and vectors, i.e.:

$$A = U \Sigma U^\mathrm{T}$$

with $\Sigma$ given by the same $\lambda_i$’s:

$$\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
-\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_2 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -\lambda_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
and $U$ a real unitary (orthogonal) matrix.

Is there any relationship between $V$ and $U$. Specifically, given $V$ (and $S$), is there an “easy” way to get $U$ (or vice-versa, $U,\Sigma\to V$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. Denote
$$
D = \pmatrix{-i & 0\\ 0 & i}, \quad J = \pmatrix{0 & 1\\ -1 & 0}, \quad W = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{i & 1\\1 & i}.
$$
We find that $W^*JW = D$. Consequently, if
$$
\Sigma = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 J \\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_k J\\ &&& 0},
$$
Then we have $\Omega^* \Sigma \Omega = S$, where
$$
\Omega = \pmatrix{W\\ & \ddots \\ && W\\ &&& I}.
$$
Now, if $A = VSV^*$, then $A = V\Omega^* \Sigma \Omega V^* = (V\Omega^*)\Sigma (V \Omega^*)^*$. In other words, if we are given $V$, then $U = V\Omega^*$. Conversely, if we are given $U$, then $V = U\Omega$.

Comment: Thanks. When the eigenvectors $V$ are given as conjugate pairs, the corresponding $U$ vectors are then easily obtained as $R_i+I_i$ and $R_i-I_i$, where $R_i$ and $I_i$ are the real and imaginary parts of each conjugate pair. What confused me is that apparently each pair of $U$ vectors can be further rotated by an arbitrary angle, so $U$ and $V\Omega^*$ obtained from independent decompositions are not necessarily equal (even after making sure the orders match).